# If $|F|\to1$, $|G|\to0$, and $|H|\to\infty$, then $|(F+G)H|\to\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $F,G, H: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $|F(x)| \to 1$, $|G(x)| \to 0$ and $|H(x)| \to \infty$ when $|x| \to \infty$. Then, if $Q(x) = (F(x) + G(x))H(x)$, we have
> $$
> |Q(x) | \to \infty,\ \ \text{when} \ \ |x| \to \infty 
> $$

My difficulty is in working with $|Q(x)|$. I know I need to get something like $|Q(x)| \geq C |H(x)|$. But I do not know how.

Comment: What does $F+G\rightarrow \pm 1$ tell you?

Comment: @Aruralreader  But if $|G(x)| \to 0$ does not mean that $G(x) \to 0$. For example, $G(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$.

Comment: @AndressaMask  $|G(x)|\to0\iff G(x)\to0$ (in your alledged counterexample, $|G(x)|=1\not\to0$).

Comment: @AndressaMask  I don't understand that example.  With your function, we clearly have $|G(x)|=1$.  It is, of course, true that $|F(x)|\to 1$ does not imply that $F(x)\to 1$ (and your example applies to that case).

Comment: @Aruralreader $|F|\to1\not\Rightarrow F\to\pm1$ ($F$ is complex-valued). However, $|F+G|\to1.$

Comment: If the absolute value of a number is very near $0$, so must the number be.

Comment: $|F+G| \to 1? |F(x) + G(x) -1| = |F(x) -1 + G(x)| \leq |F(x) -1| + |G(x)| < \epsilon/ 2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon $. Ok. Soon, $|F(x) + G(x)| > 1/2$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much.

Comment: No. Same comment as above: $|F|\to1\not\Rightarrow F\to1.$ The result $|F+G| \to 1$ is correct but your proof is not. Replace it with$$||F+G|-1|\le||F+G|-|F||+||F|-1|\le|G|+||F|-1|.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval True, I messed up. Thank you very much.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be the quality this stack is after.